# How to use action of people as a noun in a sentence?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

I want to express my ideas about people's action.

I hate people's painting walls.
Or

I hate walls being painted by people.

how  can I say this in a proper way.

For example, "I hate spitting out of people" . In this case, I want to say that I do not like when people split out to street etc.What is the proper ways of saying these?

Comment: *I hate people painting walls*.

*I hate people spitting* or *I hate people spitting in the street* or *I hate spitting in the street.*

Comment: Also, _I hate (it) when people spit in the street_ (The "it" is [optional](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/i-hate-when-vs-i-hate-it-when)).

Comment: Now that you mention it, TV tells me the *it* is optional in US America. Here in the UK, it's mandatory. Hmm…

Answer (score 1):

*I hate people painting walls*.

*I hate people spitting* or *I hate people spitting in the street* or *I hate spitting in the street*.

Comment: OP does not hate people, but the walls painted by people

Comment: Correct, OP does not hate the people but nor does he hate the walls. He hates the action.

Context and natural usage both say "people painting walls" is not treated as two nouns separated by a verb, but some special combination. 

Worse, the action he hates is not simply painting but painting walls, or the result of it… not quite the same but both expressed the same way.

Then, the grammar can't but the context does suggest even that is only in special circumstances.

Does it becomes more obvious in the more likely, more topical reference "I hate councils felling trees"?

Comment: I don't know why, but I still see *I hate councils felling trees* as *I hate councils who fell trees* (I suppose by *councils* you meant *officials*)

Comment: Andrew, that’s starting to put too many horses before the same cart and you might start separate threads. Whatever else no; councils there meant exactly councils, not anything like officials though here, thats a side issue. 

There are plenty of WWW pages conjugating verbs and explaining their tenses and if you drop the rest of the sentence, does it help to see that felling trees and who fell trees aren’t the same here; felling and who fell less so?

Hate ‘em or love ‘em, with out without councils or trees, felling is an activity, as asked for; who fell is a classification.